# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Parenting's [first moderator election](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Joe]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

As you might recall, this is a [special *pro tempore* moderator election](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election), which means Joe will need to run for re-election along with the rest of the moderators in the event this site graduates.

Please join me in thanking Erica who is stepping down at this time. She's been a wonderful addition to the team and I hope she'll continue to be a part of this site for years to come.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6557382805028864/0).

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for everyone's support and confidence, and I hope to be a helpful member of the moderating team for years to come!

I hope everyone will join me in thanking Erica in her hard work on behalf of the site, and wish her well both as a member of the community and in everything that she does!

Comment: Congrats Joe! よろしくお願いします！

Comment: Many congratulations Joe! And commiserations to the other candidates!

Comment: Thank you, Joe, and congratulations and best wishes as you go forward :)

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to you Joe, our new moderator!